# The Atom Riddles #3

Tags: riddle, science

[Link to other riddles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A56715+title%3A%22The+Atom+Riddles%22)

**Rules**:

- Again, you are trapped in a room by the mad scientist.
- There are clues in the sentences. You have to find the correct atomic element that matches the clues.

Here is the riddle (I probably made it too easy).

> One fifth of air; 
> without me you wouldn't exist.

> What am I?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a riddle as much as regular trivia; the clues are very straightforward.

Comment: Probably tells me I'm not very good as a riddle-maker. Take a look at my other riddles

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be a trivia question rather than a puzzle.

Comment: @zixuan I have. They also seemed quite like trivia to me, but this one is the most blatant trivia so I finally decided to bring it up.  You could try browsing our questions on [riddle creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation+riddle), there is some good advice there.

Comment: Also, please don't vandalize your question by crossing out the important text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Oxygen

One fifth of air

> Oxygen makes up 21% of the Earth's atmosphere

Without me, you wouldn't exist

> Humans need Oxygen to survive

Comment: Haha! Bet me by 7 secs.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

> Oxygen

Reasons

> Oxygen is about one-fifth of the atmosphere (~ 21 %)
>  And oxygen is essential for us (Aerobic) to live

Comment: Sorry, but you were beaten by @Nilster by 7 seconds!

Comment: Yep! I saw.. :'(